24.04 on Lenovo Legion Pro 5i hangs on filesystem check
A couple of months ago I installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my Lenovo laptop (Legion Pro 5i Gen 8 Intel (16") with RTX 4050), which went well until one of the updates. Since then, for the past three weeks or so, most often when I power up I get the "Press Ctrl+C to cancel all filesystem checks in progress," after which everything hangs. I can successfully boot after either, 1) using grub to boot Windows, then exiting and restarting, or 2) booting from thumb drive and running boot-repair - however, almost inevitably, once I shut down from Ubuntu, I get the filesystem check hang again and have do the workaround. What can I do to get rid of this issue?
Below is a sample boot-repair log:
Paste from boot-repair 20 September 2024 2:48 +0000

This paste expires on 2024-10-21.

Syntax highlighting: bash
View raw

boot-repair-4ppa2081                                              [20240919_2247]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================





modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.8.0-44-generic

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p6,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups


rm /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
Mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot/efi

=================== Reinstall the grub-efi of /dev/nvme0n1p6 ===================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.12-1ubuntu7
modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.8.0-44-generic
modprobe efivars

efibootmgr -v (filtered) before grub install
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0004,2003,2002,2001
Boot0000* EFI USB Device (SanDisk)  UsbWwid(781,5575,0,4C53000014061720040)/CDROM(1,0x1e4,0x8000)RC
Boot0001* EFI PXE 0 for IPv4 (FC-5C-EE-30-26-E9)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1b,0x5)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(fc5cee3026e9,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0002* EFI PXE 0 for IPv6 (FC-5C-EE-30-26-E9)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1b,0x5)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(fc5cee3026e9,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0003* Ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,461da295-c68b-4b05-94d1-fe4e1a54505e,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,461da295-c68b-4b05-94d1-fe4e1a54505e,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000000000100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC

uname -r
6.8.0-44-generic

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/nvme0n1p1
mv /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

efibootmgr -v (filtered) after grub install
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0004,2003,2002,2001
Boot0000* EFI USB Device (SanDisk)  UsbWwid(781,5575,0,4C53000014061720040)/CDROM(1,0x1e4,0x8000)RC
Boot0001* EFI PXE 0 for IPv4 (FC-5C-EE-30-26-E9)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1b,0x5)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(fc5cee3026e9,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0002* EFI PXE 0 for IPv6 (FC-5C-EE-30-26-E9)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1b,0x5)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(fc5cee3026e9,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0003* Ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,461da295-c68b-4b05-94d1-fe4e1a54505e,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,461da295-c68b-4b05-94d1-fe4e1a54505e,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000000000100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
Warning: NVram was not modified.

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic
Found memtest86+ 64bit EFI image: /boot/memtest86+x64.efi
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p6/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p6: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

nvme0n1p7: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on nvme0n1p6
OS#2 (windows):   Windows 8 or 10 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: AD107M [GeForce RTX 4050 Max-Q / Mobile] Alder Lake-S [UHD Graphics] from NVIDIA Corporation Intel Corporation
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-44-generic root=UUID=588fb6f1-98fa-42f6-9aa5-591d47c15246 ro quiet splash video=eDP-1:1920×1080@164.83 vt.handoff=7
df -Th / : /dev/nvme0n1p6 ext4   55G   27G   26G  52% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: KWCN42WW(1.42) from LENOVO
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0004,2003,2002,2001
Boot0000* EFI USB Device (SanDisk)  UsbWwid(781,5575,0,4C53000014061720040)/CDROM(1,0x1e4,0x8000)RC
Boot0001* EFI PXE 0 for IPv4 (FC-5C-EE-30-26-E9)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1b,0x5)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(fc5cee3026e9,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0002* EFI PXE 0 for IPv6 (FC-5C-EE-30-26-E9)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1b,0x5)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(fc5cee3026e9,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0003* Ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,461da295-c68b-4b05-94d1-fe4e1a54505e,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,461da295-c68b-4b05-94d1-fe4e1a54505e,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000000000100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p6   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p7   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p5   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p6   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
nvme0n1p7   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p6   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p7   : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no-kernel,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: C5B35749-C62F-4E21-911C-AD5AAFF5606A
              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1       2048     534527     532480   260M EFI System
nvme0n1p2     534528     567295      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3     567296  460312575  459745280 219.2G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4  460312576  869912575  409600000 195.3G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p5 1996312576 2000408575    4096000     2G Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p6  869912576  987099135  117186560  55.9G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p7  987099136 1996312575 1009213440 481.2G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:SAMSUNG MZVL21T0HCLR-00BL2:;
1:1049kB:274MB:273MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:274MB:290MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:290MB:236GB:235GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:236GB:445GB:210GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
6:445GB:505GB:60.0GB:ext4::;
7:505GB:1022GB:517GB:ext4::;
5:1022GB:1024GB:2097MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                        
nvme0n1                                                                                                    
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     78A8-5AD8                            461da295-c68b-4b05-94d1-fe4e1a54505e SYSTEM_DRV  EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               04ab56c6-2bff-4081-b120-2711dd0ca477             Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     B8D6A92CD6A8EC36                     576dce49-d35d-411d-a819-fc323da4448d Windows-SSD Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     E2E09CC6E09CA1F9                     d1b543e5-b0f3-4bbc-8e68-9ec3a68da2ae New Volume  Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p5 ntfs     42DCA98DDCA97C33                     115b8639-8099-4a42-afa1-932a9329fd6b WINRE_DRV   Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p6 ext4     588fb6f1-98fa-42f6-9aa5-591d47c15246 35c2e17b-74e6-4599-a15f-3ce085ce39f7             
└─nvme0n1p7 ext4     35b0a598-dd0c-447f-b55b-d9a9596ba3a5 494e86a3-216c-4409-a62c-184edea46f07             

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                     Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p3                       78.2G  64% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4                      116.1G  41% /media/dungeon
/dev/nvme0n1p5                        1.2G  41% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/nvme0n1p6                         25G  49% /
/dev/nvme0n1p7                      111.5G  71% /home
efivarfs                            108.2K  58% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p3                      fuseblk                            rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p4                      fuseblk                            rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p5                      fuseblk                            rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p6                      ext4                               rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p7                      ext4                               rw,relatime

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 588fb6f1-98fa-42f6-9aa5-591d47c15246 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p6/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   588fb6f1-98fa-42f6-9aa5-591d47c15246
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p1)   osprober-efi-78A8-5AD8
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p6/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=588fb6f1-98fa-42f6-9aa5-591d47c15246 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=78A8-5AD8  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/nvme0n1p7 during installation
UUID=35b0a598-dd0c-447f-b55b-d9a9596ba3a5 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
UUID=E2E09CC6E09CA1F9  /media/dungeon  ntfs defaults,fmask=133,dmask=022,gid=1000,uid=1000  0  0

==================== nvme0n1p6/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=eDP-1:1920×1080@164.83"
GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"
export GRUB_MENU_PICTURE=""
export GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="light-gray/magenta"
export GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="red/blue"
GRUB_FONT="/boot/grub/unicode.pf2"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

================= nvme0n1p6: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 433.052635193 = 464.986726400  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 463.914310455 = 498.124197888  boot/vmlinuz                                   2
 459.218997955 = 493.082644480  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic                  2
 429.728511810 = 461.417476096  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-44-generic                  2
 463.914310455 = 498.124197888  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic                  2
 429.728511810 = 461.417476096  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 466.541011810 = 500.944596992  boot/initrd.img                                9
 444.168998718 = 476.922830848  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic               3
 444.270534515 = 477.031854080  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-44-generic               2
 466.541011810 = 500.944596992  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic               9
 444.270534515 = 477.031854080  boot/initrd.img.old                            2

=================== nvme0n1p6: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18133 Apr  4 06:12 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Apr  4 06:12 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14513 Apr  4 06:12 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Apr  4 06:12 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Apr  4 06:12 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Apr  4 06:12 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Apr  5 07:36 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec 18  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec 18  2022 41_custom
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 May  2 23:40 backup

New paste
Poster:

Your name (30 characters max)
Syntax:
Expiration:

Approximate and not guaranteed
Content:
© 2024 Canonical Ltd. Ubuntu and Canonical are registered trademarks of Canonical Ltd.

    Legal info 

Go to the top of the page

